# Find the following limit: $\lim \limits_{x,y \to 0,0} \frac{x+y-\frac{1}{2}y^2}{\sin\left(y\right)+\log\left(1+x\right)}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Recently I came upon a limit which confused me. The reason is that when I try to solve the following limit using polar coordinates I get a constant which I do not know if it gives me information.

Let : $$\lim_{x,y \to 0} \frac{x+y-\frac{1}{2}y^2}{\sin\left(y\right)+\log\left(1+x\right)}$$
Using polar coordnates I get this: 
$$\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{r\cos\left(\theta\right)+r\sin\left(\theta\right)-\frac{1}{2}r^2\sin^2\left(\theta\right)}{\sin\left(r\sin\left(\theta\right)\right)+\log\left(1+r\cos\left(\theta\right)\right)}$$

Which is equal to:
$$\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{r\cos\left(\theta\right)+r\sin\left(\theta\right)-\frac{1}{2}r^2\sin^2\left(\theta\right)}{r\sin\left(\theta\right)+r\cos\left(\theta\right)}=1$$
I already know this limit does not exist. Actually it was quite difficult to find a path for which I get a different limit...

My question is: If I use polar coordinates and the result is not something that depends on $r,\theta$ then what I get is basically useless information? (I know that if that limit goes to infinity the limit of the function does not exist)

Comment: I have doubts about going from the second equation to the third.

Comment: I have been fighting with this limit since yesterday, may be I made a mistake. But I can not see it right now.

Comment: My first thought would be to consider paths of approach where the numerator is constant. Then think about the cases with the constant being $0$ and it being $1$. If you get a nonzero limit in the second case, you are done since the limit in the first case is zero.

Comment: Actually if you approach with the parabola $x=y^2-y$ the limit is equal to  1/2 which proves the limit does not exist.

Comment: @TheNicouU Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

- $x=0,\, y=t\to 0 \implies \frac{x+y-\frac{1}{2}y^2}{\sin\left(y\right)+\log\left(1+x\right)}=\frac{t-\frac{1}{2}t^2}{\sin\left(t\right)}\to 1$
- $x=-t+\frac12t^2,\, y=t,\, t\to 0 \implies \frac{x+y-\frac{1}{2}y^2}{\sin\left(y\right)+\log\left(1+x\right)}
  =\frac{-t+\frac12t^2+t-\frac12t^2}{\sin\left(t\right)+\log\left(1-t+\frac12t^2\right)}=0$